# Present Perfect Continous + attributive adjective or Present Perfect + predicative adjective + adverbial clause

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Here is a sentence which meaning I can't understand clearly:

> Ever since I was a child I have been happiest living in the sphere of a story. [[Source](http://www.katebernheimer.com/images/Fairy%20Tale%20is%20Form.pdf)]

Does "happiest" relate to "living" (attributive adjective) or to "I" (predicative adjective)?
What tenses are used here?

Is it

```
  Present Perfect Continuous (have been living)   
  Present Perfect (have been happiest) + adverbial clause (living)
```

or maybe something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of this as  clause with *when* missing:

> Ever since I was a child I have been happiest **when** living in the
>   sphere of a story.

**Happiest** is adjectival.

For present perfect continuous, you'd need an adverb in that position:

> The sea level has been **most rapidly** rising in the Southern Ocean.

Answer (score 1):

> Ever since I was a child **I have been happiest** living in the sphere of a story.

The base phrase is "I have been happiest (how)", *happiest* refers to "I".

However you could say:

> Ever since I was a child I have been **living happily** in the sphere of a story.

In this example, *happily* modifies *living*.